# Deformation due to isostatic compression

Tags: solid-mechanics

When loading a solid material in the shape of a cylinder in isostatic compression, what is the relationship for the change in length versus change in diameter?

For example.  If I know that when I apply an isostatic load of 6000 psi to a cylindrical core of rock that is initially at a volume of 11,351 cc the deformation will be ~10.8 cc.  Knowing the initial length and diameter of my cylinder, how do I predict the new length and diameter?

Comment: Look up bulk modulus. It is defined as change in pressure over change is volume $K =-V \frac{ \Delta P}{\Delta V}$.

Comment: @ja72 Yes that is right. I figured my rock compressibility to be 1.58 x 10^-7 psi^-1 which would give me the correct bulk modulus of -6,329,114 psi. For a right cylinder $\delta V = \pi (2hr\delta r + r^2 \delta h) $. Knowing this relation, how do I figure how much my radius will change and how much my height will change?

Comment: See my answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your example the [bulk modulus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulk_modulus) of the rock sample is

$$ K = -V \frac{\Delta P}{\Delta V} = -11351\,{\rm cm^3} \frac{ 6000\,{\rm psi}}{10.8\,{\rm cm^3}} = -6300 \; {\rm ksi} $$

Given an applied pressure $P$ then the change in volume is $\Delta V =- \frac{V\;  P}{K}$. Given a small linear expansion/contraction of the cylinder volume the dimension changes are

$$ \Delta L = \frac{\Delta V}{3 \pi r^2} $$
  $$ \Delta r = \frac{\Delta V}{3 \pi L r} $$

where $L$ is the length of the cylinder and $r$ its radius.

*Check*

$$ V + \Delta V \approx \pi (r + \Delta r)^2 (L + \Delta L) $$
$$ \Delta V \approx \pi (r + \frac{\Delta V}{3 \pi L r})^2 (L + \frac{\Delta V}{3 \pi r^2}) - \pi r ^2 L $$
$$ \Delta V = \Delta V + {\rm O}(\Delta V^2) + \ldots$$

which checks out if we ignore higher order terms for $\Delta V$.

*Details*

Given $V + \Delta V \approx \pi (r + \Delta r)^2 (L + \Delta L)$ and the proportional response $\frac{\Delta r}{\Delta L} = \frac{r}{L}$ as well as $V=\pi r^2 L$ combined you get

$$ \pi r^2 L + \Delta V = \pi (r + \frac{r}{L} \Delta L)^2 (L + \Delta L) $$
  $$ \pi r^2 L + \Delta V = \pi r^2 L + 3\pi r^2 \Delta L + \ldots $$
  $$ \Delta V = 3\pi r^2 \Delta L $$

and

$$ \Delta V = 3\pi r L \Delta r $$

Comment: You find this by fixing the scale as $\frac{\Delta r}{\Delta L} = \frac{r}{L}$ and plugging it into $V+\Delta V$ expression. Then ignore any higher order terms of $\Delta V$ since we want the response to a relatively small $\Delta V$ (for linearity).

Comment: I understand what you are saying.  If you don't mind, can you show your derivation for $\Delta L$ and $\Delta r$?  Calculus isn't my strong point and when I derivate V I don't exactly see how you got those relations

Comment: No calculus needed. Plug $\Delta r = \frac{r}{L} \Delta L$ into $V + \Delta V \approx \pi (r + \Delta r)^2 (L + \Delta L)$ and ignore everything that is $\Delta L^2$ and above.

Comment: See if you can follow now.

Comment: $\Delta V = \pi (r+\Delta r)^2 +(L+\Delta L) - \pi r^2 L$ $\Delta V = \pi (8.89+0.0028)^2 (45.72+0.0144) - \pi 8.89^2 45.71 = 10.8$ so what is the problem?

Comment: No problem. I erroneously tried $\Delta V = \pi \cdot 0.0028^2 \cdot 0.0144 = 3.54 \times 10^{-7}$ and was confused as to why it wasn't 10.8

Comment: Here is basically the same thing you did, just in a slightly different manner. $$V = \pi r^2 h$$ therefore $$\Delta V = \pi (2hr\Delta r + r^2 \Delta h)$$ by substituting our assumption $$\frac{\Delta r}{\Delta h} = \frac{r}{h}$$ we solve for our variable of interest, for example $\Delta r$ where $\Delta h = \frac{h}{r} \Delta r$: $$\Delta V = \pi (2hr\Delta r + r^2 \frac{h}{r} \Delta r)$$ $$\Delta r = \frac{\Delta V}{3\pi r h}$$